# Render Highcharts inside Webix

Tags: ruby-on-rails, highcharts, webix

I'm rendering [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) chart in the Rails app like this and it works fine:

```
  #container
    #report-box
      = render 'chart'
```

However, I want to show this chart inside [Webix scrollview](http://docs.webix.com/api__refs__ui.scrollview.html). Now my code looks like this and is not working (no errors, only blank space where the chart should be):

```
#section3{:style => "display:none;"}
  #container{:height => "800px", :width => "1100px"}
    #report-box
      = render 'chart'

webix.ui({view:"layout",
    container:"scroll",
    rows:[
        {view: "scrollview", id: "sections", height: 600,
         scroll: "y",
         body:{
            { id: "section_3", template: "html->section3", height: 300}
         }
    ]
});

function scroll(id){
    $$("sections").showView("section_"+id);
  };
```

I would appreciate any ideas on how to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to render Highcharts only with the help of [webix-highcharts](https://github.com/marcpmichel/webix-highcharts)